# Android - How to combine two ArrayLists

Tags: java, android, arrays, loops, arraylist

I have got two ArrayLists, created from parsed html. First one contains jobs and is like

```
Job A
Job B
Job C
```

and the second one is like

```
Company A
Company B
Company C
```

What I need is combination of Job A and Company A and so on, so I can get the results like (an ArrayList too would be great)

```
Job A : Company A
Job B : Company B
Job C : Company C
```

I didn't find clear tutorial or something. Any ideas?

Comment: Create a Java class that represents the relationship (e.g., `Position`). Iterate through the arrays, creating `Position` objects for each job/company pair, putting those `Position` objects into an `ArrayList<Position>`.

Comment: Are the ArrayList in any particular order? So jobList.get(i) will always be aligned with companyList.get(i). You may want to work on developing your question if you want a solid answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you sure you are looking at the correct data structure to achieve this?

Why not use a [Map](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html)? You can define a key/value relationship going this route.

```
Map<Company, Job> jobMap = new HashMap<Company, Job>();
jobMap.put("Company A" /* or corresponding list item */, "Job A" /* or corresponding list item */);
```

You may even do something like this: (Swap out the strings to your to fit your implementation)

```
Map<Company, List<Job>> jobMap...;
List<Job> jobList = new ArrayList<Job>();
jobList.add("Job A");
jobList.add("Job B");
jobList.add("Job C");
jobMap.put("Company A", jobList);
```

What this will do is define a company as your key and you can set multiple jobs to a company

Answer (score 1):

```
if (jobs.length() != companies.length()) {
    throw new InvalidArgumentException("Mismatch of jobs and companies");
}

for (int i = 0; i < jobs.length(); i++) {
   combine(jobs.get(i), companies.get(i));
}
```

There are lots of ways to combine references between two kinds of objects.  Here's a flexible example that will let you use one to look up the other.  It's overkill if you know which you'd always be using to do the lookup.  Using `LinkedHashMap` also preserves the insertion order.  So if you decide to put them in B, C, A order, you can get them out in B, C, A order.

```
LinkedHashMap<Job, Company> jobToCompany = new LinkedHashMap<>();
LinkedHashMap<Company, Job> companyToJob = new LinkedHashMap<>();

private void combine(Job job, Company company) {
    jobToCompany.put(job, company);
    companyToJob.put(company, job);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're not willing to use a Map (not sure why you would that) my approach would be: To create another class (lets call it CompanyJob) that would contain both a Company and a Job attribute, then simply have a collection of your CompanyJob instances (an ArrayList would do).

```
class CompanyList{
  private Company mCompany;
  private Job mJob;
  public CompanyList (Company com, Job job){
    mCompany = com;
    mJob = job;
  }
  // Some logic ...
}
// Then your list
private ArrayList<CompanyList> yourList = new ArraList <>();
int i = 0;
for (Company tmpCom: companyList){
  yourList.add (new CompanyJob (tmpCom,jobList.get(i));
  i++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to store the combined values in an `ArrayList` then the following code will work for you:

```
List<String> jobs = new ArrayList<>(); 
List<String> companies = new ArrayList<>();
List<String> mergedList = new ArrayList<>();
//assuming the value are populated for `jobs` and `companies`. 
if(jobs.size() == companies.size()) {
    int n = jobs.size();
    for(int index=0; index<n; index++)
    {
        mergedList.add(jobs.get(index) + " : " + companies.get(index))
    }
} else {
    System.out.println("Cannot combine");
    //Throw exception or take any action you need.
}
```

Keep in mind that if you need to search for any item it would be O(n) but I assume you are aware of it before taking decision of going with an `ArrayList`.

Answer (score -1):

You need to create a new one

```
List<String> third = new ArrayList<String>();
```

Also need a counter.

```
int position = 0;
```

Then iterate through the list (considering the size is same for both the list).

```
for(String item:firstList){
third.add(item+ " : " + secondList.get(position);
position ++;
}
```

Then the **third** will have the desired result.

**To confirm:**

```
for (String item:third){
//try to print "item" here
}
```

Comment: No sure what is the reason for downvote. The question looks to seek for the same process

Comment: It looks like the title and the question that OP is asking are different. `What I need is combination of Job A and Company A and so on, so I can get the results like (an ArrayList too would be great)`

Comment: I am waiting for OP for the response. Will delete it if it's of no use.